# Converting a Data Frame into a Time Series in R

Tags: r, time-series

I have a weird problem with converting a data frame into a time series:

1) I have a data frame which has 420,000 rows. It looks like:

```
 > numsdf[5760:5764,]

              YR--MODAHRMN TEMP DEWP
 7712 1973-04-29 00:00:00   82   35
 7713 1973-04-29 01:00:00   78   41
 7714 1973-04-29 02:00:00   73   45
 7715 1973-04-29 03:00:00   66   41
 7716 1973-04-29 04:00:00   61   46
```

2) I convert this into a time series. No problem up to here.

```
> tsdf=with(numsdf, xts(numsdf$TEMP, order.by = numsdf$"YR--MODAHRMN"))
```

3) Problem 1: For some reason the TEMP column becomes V1. No idea why.

```
 > tsdf[5760:5764,]
                      [,1]
 1973-04-29 00:00:00   82
 1973-04-29 01:00:00   78
 <NA>                  73
 1973-04-29 03:00:00   66
 1973-04-29 04:00:00   61
```

3) Problem 2:

Some dates, (randomly and for no apparent reason) are changed to . As in the example above, I don't know why this happens. Thanks

Comment: See `? xts` for problem 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `TEMP` column becomes `V1` because `numsdf$TEMP` is a vector and doesn't have a column name, so the xts constructor gives it a default column name of `V1`.

Some datetimes are likely `NA` because they occur when daylight saving time starts in your local timezone.

You need to provide more specific details (via a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/271616)) if you want people to be able to provide more specific solutions.

Comment: Thank you very much. I noticed this is the second time you answer my questions and I thank you enormously. I'll work on providing a good reproducible example next time.